# ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found in java

Tags: java

When trying Apple push notifications from a Java server using a p12 file, I get an error. Is there a problem with my p12 file or my Java code?

```
run:
@:theodore nonis
C=IN, CN=Apple Development IOS Push Services: com.ducont.myPushApp, UID=com.ducont.myPushApp
theodore nonis
ok
init Stores...
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:174)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1591)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:187)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:181)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:975)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:123)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:516)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:454)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:884)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1096)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1123)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1107)
        at javatest.Main.APNSender(Main.java:88)
        at javatest.Main.main(Main.java:114)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found
        at sun.security.validator.SimpleValidator.buildTrustedChain(SimpleValidator.java:304)
        at sun.security.validator.SimpleValidator.engineValidate(SimpleValidator.java:107)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:218)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:209)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:249)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:954)
        ... 9 more
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)
```

Comment: This appears to mean that you have an empty truststore. You don't show any code or setup, or who prints the output shown, or what it is, which makes it impossible to comment further.

Answer (score 0):

Try below steps for windows:

Download jars from here https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html

Copy local_policy.jar and US_export_policy.jar to the $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security (Note: these jars will be already there so you have to overwrite them).

Then restart your application to get rid of this exception.

Comment: The posted exception can never be caused by crypto policy, the Q was posted in 2012 well before j8 existed, and for 8u161 up (including _all_ 9,10,11) the policy issue no longer exists and this can only hurt, and in cases where policy _is_ the problem it's the same on all platforms not just Windows.

Answer (score -1):

this might be caused by java 1.9, switch to java 1.8 might resolve your problem.

Comment: Neither j8 nor j9 existed in 2012, and neither causes the problem in this Q.

Answer (score -2):

This is certificate problem. There can be two solutions:

1 Use trusted certificate

2 Disable certificate checking. For plain java code it can be done that way ([read here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-fix-certificate-problem-in-HTTPS.html)).

In p12 should be some possibility to set up TrustManages.

Comment: How to create trusted p12 file for push notification?

Comment: You cannot create trusted certificate, you can only bay it.

Comment: is there any way to check p12 file trusted or not in java?